# how to replace all characters of a header

Tags: php, date, replace, header, uniqueidentifier

How can i replace all `__Chr(__Rand(98,122))` and `__Chr(__Rand(97,122))` values with the real php function `chr(rand(97,122))` that give a random and with the same parameters in generic way here is the header :

```
Reply-To: __Reply-To
Bounces_to: __Bounce
Message-ID: <__Chr(__Rand(97,122))__Chr(__Rand(98,122)).__X-Mailer@__From_dn>
X-BFI: __Chr(__Rand(97,122))__Chr(__Rand(98,122))
From: __To
```

Comment: are you creating the headers? Or are you being given the headers and need to modify them?

Comment: i need to modify the given one Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this, i.e.:

```
<?php
$header = <<< LOB
Reply-To: __Reply-To
Bounces_to: __Bounce
Message-ID: <__Chr(__Rand(97,122))__Chr(__Rand(98,122)).__X-Mailer@__From_dn>
X-BFI: __Chr(__Rand(97,122))__Chr(__Rand(98,122))
From: __To
LOB;

function charCallback($matches){
$charOne = (int)$matches[1];
$charTwo = (int)$matches[2];
return chr(rand($charOne,$charTwo));
}

echo  preg_replace_callback('/__Chr\(__Rand\((\d+),(\d+)\)\)/', 'charCallback', $header);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Reply-To: __Reply-To
Bounces_to: __Bounce
Message-ID: <uw.__X-Mailer@__From_dn>
X-BFI: jn
From: __To
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/AMdRcN)

Comment: it gave me this chr(rand(97,122))chr(rand(98,122)) the php didnt compile them ! this is a php function and it should give a random

Comment: Hum...didn't understand you need that, let me take a look.

Comment: thank you very much Pedro im waiting for your next response i wish to make it work :)

Comment: You're very welcome @dravos, check the update answer ;)